# Is there a way to determine exactly what operator a Perl B::LOGOP object refers to?

Tags: perl

From playing with [B](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.1/ext/B/B.pm), I see that a `B::LOGOP` object (call it "`$op`") referring to either a `&&` or `and` operator will both return "and" upon calling `$op->name`. Is it possible to determine which operator the LOGOP refers to merely by examining `$op`?

Comment: Once you have the precedence figured out, it doesn't matter which one it is. What are you trying to do?

Comment: brian: whether it matters depends on what one is trying to do. I'm just fiddling with B and PadWalker and have decided it matters for my fiddling purposes. And maybe I want to do something ridiculous later, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not expert for perl internals, but `LOGOP` refers to logical operator group. So I don't think you can know individual operator without examining the name. Even [B::Terse](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?B%3a%3aTerse) displays it:

```
perl -MO=Terse -e '$a && $b'
```

Shows:

```
....
        LOGOP (0x198ad94) and
            UNOP (0x198adec) null [15]
                PADOP (0x198ae08) gvsv  GV (0x187bb9c) *a
            UNOP (0x198adb4) null [15]
                PADOP (0x198add0) gvsv  GV (0x187bc9c) *b
```